# How to rearrange a pandas table where data is split between multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that contains table data taken from online, where there are pairs of data split into multiple columns like this every 2 columns:

```
| name   | price | name.1 | price.1| name.2 | price.2|
|--------|-------|--------|--------|--------|--------|
| orange | 2.2   | banana | 3.1    | grapes | 1.8    |
| apple  | 2.5   | mango  | 4.2    | kiwi   | 2.4    |
```

is there a way to rearrange the table to end up with this?:

```
| name   | price |
|--------|-------|
| orange | 2.2   |
| apple  | 2.5   |
| banana | 3.1   |
| mango  | 4.2   |
| grapes | 1.8   |
| kiwi   | 2.4   |
```

Comment: The proposed duplicate only shows how to melt/unstack the dataframe, not how to normalize and pivot back to two columns. @Nk03

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative with `np.reshape` (as this DataFrame is so conveniently structured):

```
pd.DataFrame(
    df.values.reshape(-1, 2),
    columns=['name', 'price'])
```

Output:

```
     name price
0  orange   2.2
1  banana   3.1
2  grapes   1.8
3   apple   2.5
4   mango   4.2
5    kiwi   2.4
```

Comment: Nice numpy option =)

Comment: @HenryEcker I think I messed up the order though, so if you care about the order, then yours is probably better :)

Comment: As always, it depends on what the goal is and what aspects of the data are important.

Comment: Absolutely agree

Comment: thanks, this solution worked great. There wasn't any need to preseve the order of the data so no problem there

Answer (score 2):

Try [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html#pandas-wide-to-long):

```
new_df = pd.wide_to_long(df.rename(columns={'name': 'name.0',
                                            'price': 'price.0'})
                         .reset_index(),
                         stubnames=['name', 'price'],
                         sep='.',
                         i='index',
                         j='level_1').reset_index(drop=True)
```

`new_df`:

```
     name  price
0  orange    2.2
1   apple    2.5
2  banana    3.1
3   mango    4.2
4  grapes    1.8
5    kiwi    2.4
```

---

`df` constructor:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['orange', 'apple'],
    'price': [2.2, 2.5],
    'name.1': ['banana', 'mango'],
    'price.1': [3.1, 4.2],
    'name.2': ['grapes', 'kiwi'],
    'price.2': [1.8, 2.4]
})
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked along with perls (chose that one due to succintness)

Comment: Yeah Perl's is the better option if order doesn't need maintained. =) Don't forget to  [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) Perl's answer @ashjdvyjuq234juy124

Answer (score 1):

You could also try the [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html):

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
import pandas as pd
df.pivot_longer(names_to = ('name', 'price'), 
                names_pattern = ('name', 'price')
                )
 
     name  price
0  orange    2.2
1   apple    2.5
2  banana    3.1
3   mango    4.2
4  grapes    1.8
5    kiwi    2.4
```

Your columns have a pattern (some start with `name`, others with `price`), so you pass that pattern to `names_pattern`, and pass the new column names to `names_to`.